# how can show only marker on map but default info Window or custom infowindow should not shown on marker click?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, android-maps-v2

I have  one google map(v2) with so many markers (around 1000) .I need one condition if distance is 2 km or more marker should not clickable. i already found distance but default window open on all marker .Is it possible infowindow should open when distance<2 otherwise not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning null if the distance is greater than 2, return an empty View.

```
View emptyView = new View(getActivity());

googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        if (distance < 2)
            return LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        else return emptyView;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            View view = null;
            if (distance<2) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(ChatMapActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.map_window, null);
            }
            return view;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have one custom window: mapView.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());

Comment: if (distance <= 2) {
    mapinit();} else {
    infoWindow = null;
    Log.e("log_tag","balloon");
    
   }

Answer (score 1):

You should set an OnMarkerClickListener on your map doing something like:

```
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
            double distance = 0.0; // getDistance
            // return true if you handled the click, false for default action (show window)
            return distance > 2.0;
        }
    });
```

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html#onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker)